# ref object has value for the first time, but ref.current is null

Tags: reactjs, use-ref

Could anyone explain this behavior please?
How is it that ref object has value for the first time, but ref.current is null ?
Actually the second part (ref.current = null ) is something I already know but the first part is surprising.

```
export default function App() {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState(0);
  const ref = React.useRef<HTMLButtonElement>(null);
  console.log(ref); // output: {current: HTMLButtonElement}
  console.log(ref.current); // output: null for the first time
                            // output: <button>click</button> after changing the state

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => setState(state + 1)} ref={ref}>
        click
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Seem somehow,ref, refers to something like a interface but ref.current refers to the value itself

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
How is it that ref object has value for the first time
```

It doesn't. The object was actually `{ current: null }` at the time the log statement was hit. To prove this, change the line to:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(ref));
```

The reason it looks like the object has a value is that the developer tools don't evaluate the object until you click on it in the dev tools, and by that time it has a value.